# facing issues while using phrase query with slop in LUCENE

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, phrase

I am facing some issues with phrase query, so write a small code to exactly know how phrase query actually works with slop stuff:

I have a string "abc institute of technology" and I indexed different combination of this string(more like a shingle) like this

```
Document doc = new Document();
ArrayList<String> sh = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     sh.add("abc institute engineering technology");
     sh.add("abc institute engineering");
     sh.add("abc institute");
     sh.add("abc");
     sh.add("institute engineering technology");
     sh.add("institute engineering");
     sh.add("institute");
     sh.add("engineering technology");
     sh.add("engineering");
     sh.add("technology");
  for(String s : sh){
        doc.add(new Field("insti_shingles", s.toLowerCase(), Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
  }
  writer.addDocument(doc);
```

Now when i read all the tokens from the index directory i have these set of tokens:

```
engineering technology
abc
institute
abc institute engineering technology
technology
abc institute
abc institute engineering
institute engineering technology
engineering
institute engineering
```

Now when i search for term "abc institute technology"

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
query.add(new Term("insti_shingles", "abc institute technology"));
query.setSlop(4);
booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(booleanQuery, 30);
```

Now according to documentation of phrase query with slop, i should get some results but i am getting empty result set. But I get the result when i search for the term that is exactly as indexed token.

i think the term "abc institute technology" should get matched by token "abc institute engineering technology" when we use phrase query???

Am i doing anything wrong? Help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special tokenizer to use phrase queries with slop - indeed it will cause these queries to fail, as you have noticed.

Just tokenize using a `StandardAnalyzer`, no need to do that custom shingle stuff.

Comment: I figured it out, Here i am searching for the term "abc institute technology" in one Term but what i have to do is i need to break them down into different TERMS and then search like "abc", "institute" and "technology"